# Ionic - build está dando erro

Tags: android, angularjs, node.js, ionic, build

quando estou fazendo build com o código:

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

está dando esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual é a Solução ??